# Find duplicate values in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a code which will find the duplicate value in an array. So, far I have written below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Please enter the length of Array: ");
        int[] array = new int[6];
        for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter value for index "+i+":");
            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

        FindDuplicateInArray obj = new FindDuplicateInArray();

        obj.findDupicateInArray(array);
    }

    public void findDupicateInArray(int[] a) {
        //int pointer = a[0];
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
            for(int k =j+1;k<a.length;k++) {
                if(a[j]==a[k] && j!=k && j<k && count<=1) {
                    count++;
                    if(count==1)
                    System.out.println(a[j]);

                }

            }


        }

    }
```

But I am not getting the expected output, for example:

1. If I give value 1,2,1,4,3,1 then it is successfully finding the duplicate value 1.
2. But if I provide 2 set of duplicate value in an array, still it is finding the first duplicate.
   e.g. 1,2,1,2,1,3. It is giving output only 1.

I found the reason of incorrect result which is condition of count i.e. count is set to greater than 1 and it is not matching to first if condition.

So, I have tried to reset the counter to 0 after one loop iteration, now it is giving all duplicate values but duplicate values printing twice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Please enter the length of Array: ");
        int[] array = new int[6];
        for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter value for index "+i+":");
            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

        FindDuplicateInArray obj = new FindDuplicateInArray();

        obj.findDupicateInArray(array);
    }

    public void findDupicateInArray(int[] a) {
        //int pointer = a[0];
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
            for(int k =j+1;k<a.length;k++) {
                if(a[j]==a[k] && j!=k && j<k && count<=1) {
                    count++;
                    if(count==1)
                    System.out.println(a[j]);

                }

            }
            **count = 0;**

        }

    }
```

e.g. Input: 1,2,1,2,1,2, Output: 1 2 1 2

Please suggest how to get the correct result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right way, I have just updated your method, I hope that you will understand what was your mistake:

```
public void findDupicateInArray(int[] a) {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
            for(int k =j+1;k<a.length;k++) {
                if(a[j]==a[k]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count==1)
               System.out.println(a[j]);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Nevertheless, this will make your code running correctly, and that does not mean you have written the optimal code.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is giving me the correct result but the if in case I will provide input:

1,2,1,2,1,3, then it will give output in order 2 1 & not 1 2.

I get to know the reason that if for initial iterations it will make the count to greater than 1 and then print the value of j from the last iteration. But it is possible to print the value in order 1 2 instead of 2 1?

Comment: @Shan  Yes, it is possible; either you first sort the array and use this function to find the duplicated or you collect the duplicated values to new array and sort it and print it out.

Answer (score 5):

I do not like to use Streams or smth hight-level for solving algorythmic problem; only plain java. So this is my solution:

```
public static Set<Integer> findDuplicateInArray(int... arr) {
    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> duplicate = new HashSet<>();

    for (int val : arr)
        if (!unique.add(val))
            duplicate.add(val);

    return duplicate;
}
```

In case you are able to modify incomming `arr`, then with some small modification, you can refuce from `Set<Integer> unique`.

Comment: How to use this method?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's easier to convert the array to list and make all the logic with the Java 8 streams api in one sentence:

```
        Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3 };
    List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(numbers);         
    listInteger.stream().filter(i -> Collections.frequency(listInteger, i) >1).collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in below code it will help you.

We have to count the no of repeatation of each element and then at the last find the count, which will tell the duplicate nos.

```
    package com.java;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class FindDuplicateInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] intArr = new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 8 };

        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            // take first element and then matched complete array
            int temp = intArr[i];
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < intArr.length; j++) {
                if (temp == intArr[j]) {
                    // element matched -- break
                    count++;
                }
            }
            map.put(temp, count);
        }

        Set<Integer> duplicate = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> noDuplicate = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(intArr[i])) {
                System.out.println("Key :" + intArr[i] + " Value : " + map.get(intArr[i]));

                if (map.get(intArr[i]) > 1) {
                    // means repeated character
                    duplicate.add(intArr[i]);

                } else {
                    // non repeated character
                    noDuplicate.add(intArr[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Duplicate Chars : " + Arrays.toString(duplicate.toArray()));
        System.out.println("No Duplicate Chars : " + Arrays.toString(noDuplicate.toArray()));

    }

}
```